# Solve a first order nonlinear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have to solve the following problem:

$y'=\frac{y \cos(x)}{(1+2y^2)}$

with the initial condition $y(0)=1$.
I came up with the following equation:

$y^2(x)+\log(y(x))=\sin(x)+c_1$.

It is the first time I get such a solution and now I am not able to solve for $y(x)$. I used WolframAlpha Step by Step Solver but I really do not understand how the get $y(x)=...$. Can I solve the IVP without explicitly solve for $y(x)$?
Thank you.

Comment: Some differential equations can only be solved with implicit functions. Otherwise you'd have to use Lambert's W function to actually solve for y. Nothing wrong with an implicit solution

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. But since I have to solve an IVP, how do I actually get the value for $c_1$?

Comment: Substitute in $x=0$ and $y(0)=1$ you will be left with numbers and the constant. Since the log term will vanish

Comment: Thank you, now I understand.

Comment: No problem $\quad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct. The next step can be to determine the constant $c_1$ by initial condition, that gives:
$$
1^2+\log (1)=\sin(0)+c_1 \Rightarrow c_1=1
$$

if you want find and explicit form for $y(x)$ this can be done only using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Let $t=y^2$ and write the exponential of your equation as:
$$
\sqrt{t}e^t=e^{\sin x +1}
$$
squaring:
$$
te^{2t}=e^{2(\sin x +1)} \iff 2te^{2t}=2e^{2(\sin x +1)} 
$$
so, By definition of the W function,
$$
2t=W\left(2e^{2(\sin x +1)} \right) \iff t=\frac{1}{2}W\left(2e^{2(\sin x +1)} \right)
$$
and substituting for $y$:
$$
y=\sqrt{\frac{W\left(2e^{2(\sin x +1)} \right)}{2}}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to find the value for the constant of integration. Unfortunately, we did not cover the W function in this course!